# Connect to MongoDB hosted on AWS ec2 from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to host my web app on AWS.

I'm hosting my nodejs app on Elastic Beanstalk (salable).
I have created an ec2 instance to host my mongodb.

In test, the mongodb ec2 instance accepts connection at port 27017 from anywhere.
And my website works great.

The problems is that I want to restrict the access to mongodb ec2 instance to only allow connections from my Elastic Beanstalk app.

I changed the rule of my ec2 instance security group, to only accept tcp port 27017 connection from the security group where Elastic Beanstalk app is assigned to.

This breaks the communication to mongodb from my app immediately.

I have also tried to allow all traffic from beanstalk security group, no luck

Have I got anything wrong? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to edit the /etc/mongod.conf file and set your bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 in order to make connections externally.

Also had to try the different version of the mask to work.  xxx.xxx.0.0/16 worked for me, but xxx.xxx.0.0/24 and xxx.xxx.0.0/32 didn't.

Also, they recommended that you use the private IP if you are in the same zone (keeps costs down), but public otherwise.